# How to implement generic types with currying

Tags: java, generics, currying

Given this kind of an implementation of a generic currying:

```
public static <T, U, R> Function<T, Function<U, R>> curry(BiFunction<T, U, R> biFunction) {
        return t -> u -> biFunction.apply(t, u);
    }

 public static int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
```

And calling it like this:

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Integer>> addGen = curry(Curry::add);
System.out.println(addGen.apply(10).apply(20));
```

How can I extend this curry() function to take even more arguments? Like

```
addGen.apply(10).apply(20).apply(30)....apply(100)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: At what point does your chained curried function because a "value"?

Comment: Sorry! don't understand the question.

Comment: if the result of `foo.apply(x)` is something you can call `apply(y)` on, and the result of that is something you can call `apply(z)` on, how do you stop and get the integer value?

Comment: You need to create a `TriFunction`, a `QuadFunction`, a `NFunction` up to `N` arguments, create the proper `curry` for it and be done,

Comment: You need to write one `curry` overload for each arity, AFAIK.

Comment: @ luk2302 Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for! How can that be written with the predefined Functional Interfaces? Not making the syntax too ugly. Or do I need to create my own FI for that? If so, can you show an example? Thanks

Comment: @Prana why would you would to do this explicitly, instead of using a reduce?

Comment: @Prana The Java Standard Library only has predefined up to `BiFunction`. You'd need to create `TriFunction` and above.

Comment: @AndyTurner Could you please show me how to use a reducer in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @Sweeper Correct, I understand that. And that's why looking for such an extensible implementation of a TriFunction or QuadFunction. Thanks

Comment: @Prana `IntStream.of(10, 20, 30, ..., 100).reduce(Curry::add)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. But that is what I am looking for. Rather trying to figure out how a generic function like curry() above can be applied in this scenario. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I mean "but that is *not* what I am looking for"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean or built-in way to do this.

You could do this by defining a method with a really wild return type:

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Integer>>>>>>>>>>
```

I hope it illustrates the point that trying to approach this generically is verbose, messy, hard-to-read... (I'm not even sure I got the right number of `Function`s here).

Functions which take 10 arguments - curried or uncurried - are really not that useful. You can't even express this cleanly in a proper functional language like Haskell.

And then, what happens when you need some number other than 10. It's just a mess.

Don't try to use currying. Just treat your 10 (or however many) arguments as a list, and reduce them:

```
Stream.of(a1, ..., a10).reduce(Integer::sum)
```

Simple, clean, standard.

You could, conceivably, define an interface like:

```
interface StoppableFunction<T> extends Function<T, StoppableFunction<T>> {
  T stop();
}
```

and implement it like:

```
class Impl<T> implements StoppableFunction<T> {
  Impl(T result, BinaryFunction<T> fn) {
    this.result = result; // field defs omitted
    this.fn = fn;
  }

  public Impl<T> apply(T arg) {
    return new Impl<>(fn.apply(result, arg), fn);
  }

  T stop() {
    return result;
  }
}
```

which you can then call like:

```
new Impl<>(0, Integer::sum).apply(10).apply(20)....apply(100).stop()
```

but this isn't really currying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for the first solution mentioned in your post. As I guessed, it'd become very ugly quickly, if we try to solve it by the predefined Functional Interfaces.